# Does Microsoft Sync Framework 2.0 support Sql Server 2005 as a client?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

It appears out of the box the v1 of Microsoft Sync Framework would only support synching with a CE db, using the SqlCeClientSyncProvider.  I can't find anywhere in the documentation about v2 if we can now sync between two SQL Server databases.  Anyone know of hand if this is now possible (without writing my own client provider)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provider is the one that you should be using to sync with a SQL Server database.

```
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server.DbServerSyncProvider
```

The Local Database Cache tool could get you up and running fairly quickly without having to worry about these details - you would however be sacrificing some flexibility.

You don't necessarily need [Sync Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(SQL.105).aspx) if you do decide that you want to get a little closer to the metal but it has now been released and is probably your best bet. Just be careful with the DLL versions that you swap into your solution after installing the SDK. Note below that the database DLLs are not versioned consistently with the rest of the framework and that the version of the Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe DLL actually decreases from 3.5 to 3.0.

> Installing Sync Framework - MSDN
>
> All database provider DLLs have a
> version number of 3.0 rather than 2.0
> because some of the providers were
> originally released before Sync
> Framework 1.0.
> Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
> was originally released as part of SQL
> Server Compact and previously had a
> version number of 3.5 to match the SQL
> Server Compact version. The version of
> this DLL is now 3.0 to match the other
> database providers.